# Как выставить текст с backgraund image?

Tags: html, css

```css
.blockquote-text {
    width: 1125px;
    height: 191px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 44px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top:78px;
}

.boss {
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position:921px 42px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/img/Ellipse\ 2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.boss-text {
    width: 295px;
    height: 95px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-right: 130px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="about-blockquote">
                <p class="blockquote-text"> <span>“</span>
                    GAME OVER —
                    это место незабываемых впечатлений
                    <span>”</span> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="boss">
                <p class="boss-text" > Аркадий Абакшин,
                    создатель игровой территории GAME OVER</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Переформулируте вопрос, пожалуйста. Сейчас непонятно, в чем именно проблема, и что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 0):

`background: url(test/test.png)`, в скобках пишешь путь изображения.

Comment: то что в скобках это пример пути для изображения, если у тебя в папке то указываешь название папки потом / и название с форматом изображения

Comment: Я о том что должно быть сбоку. Как добавить картинку я знаю